# Why projectile motion equations can be reduced in certain intervals

Tags: projectile-motion

I am trying to understand projectile motion, but I have gotten stuck at the point at which they state in the limit $t >> v_t/g$ the equation is reduced, and when $t << v_t/g$ we also remove some of the equation. $>>$ means much greater than as far as I know and the other way means much less than, how do we quantify this?

I understand how the equations 184 and 187 were reached. But I do not understand why we then use 185, 186 and 188, 189?

Here is my source http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node29.html#e5.23u.

EDIT:

Also, 184 and 187 are functions that will return the $x$ and $z$ coordinates respectively given a time. I can calculate the time at which $z = 0$, i.e. when it hits the ground as that is equal to $(2v_0sin\theta)/g$. As such, the only unknown left is $v_t$. They say $v_t=m (g/c)$. Therefore, the unknown is $c$. What is $c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the limit $t << v_t/g$, you may use the approximation $e^{-x}\approx 1-x$ to get

$$1- e^{-gt/v_t}\approx \frac{gt}{v_t}$$

and hence $x= v_0\cos\theta\> t $. (Eq. 185)

In the limit $t >> v_t/g$, use the approximate $e^{-gt/v_t}\rightarrow 0$ to get

$$1- e^{-gt/v_t}\approx 1$$

and hence $x = \frac{v_0v_t\cos\theta}{g}$. (Eq. 186)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can find $c$ such that I can actually calculate some coordinates given $\theta$, $v_0$ and $m$?

Comment: Is $c$ momentum? I.e. $c = mv_0$

Comment: $c$ is the drag coefficient, which is usually given to determine the terminal velocity $v_t = mg/c$. Conversely, $c$ can be obtained if $v_t$ is known.

Comment: I need $c$ to calculate $v_t$, but I need $v_t$ to calculate $c$... How do I actually calculate any of the coordinates then?

Comment: $v_t$ is in $m/s$, and so I want the right side of the equation to be in $m/s$. Since $v_t = m g/c$, we have $kgm/s^2$ on the top and as such $c$ must be in $kgm/s$ which is momentum. So is $c = mv_0$?

Comment: One of them should be a given in the problem.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve someone's problem, I'm trying to work it out for any value myself. So, how do I determine $c$?

Comment: c is not equal to m$v_0$

Comment: Then what is it?

Comment: you need to know v_t to obtain c. In case the time of flight t is known, you could calculate v_t using 187 by setting z=0, as you described in the Edit.

Comment: So plug in $t = t_f$ and $z = 0$ then solve for $v_t$?

Comment: Right, except it is a non-linear equation to solve.

Comment: Yeah I'm having a lot of trouble doing it. How can I solve it for $v_t$?

Comment: There may not be an analytical solution; you may have to solve it numerically

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: Would it not make more sense to solve for $v_t$ in 180?