# How to solve for v

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to solve for v in this equation.

$(v/g)(ksin\theta + v)(1 - e^{-gt/v}) - vt = 0$

EDIT: Does it help if I also have the fact that $((kvcos\theta)/g)(1-e^{-gt/v}) -x = 0$? Every variable except $v$ is known in both.

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method in this case.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What does that mean?

Comment: It is impossible to do this by the known methods like squaring, subtracting and so on.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How about after my edit?

Comment: It does not help, since we have $v$ as a factor of a parenthesis and $v$ in the exponent of an exponential function.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner So how do I go about solving it with a numerical method?

Comment: If you have values for the parameters you can use the Newton Raphson method.

Comment: Or i can do it for you!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The reason I'm solving for $v$ is to determine the terminal velocity ($v_t$), and $k$ is $v_0$. I simplified it a bit. But here is my actual question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409856/graphing-the-movement-of-a-projectile-under-drag

Comment: I explain more here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409737/why-projectile-motion-equations-can-be-reduced-in-certain-intervals

Comment: So I just realised perhaps I can solve for $v_t$ in a different equation, but I plugged that into my code and $ln(v_x/(v_0cos\theta))$ keeps giving $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit you can do the following:

> From the second equation extract:
>   $$ (1-e^{-\frac{gt}{v}}) = \frac{xg}{kv\cos\theta} $$
>   Pluging this back into the first equation and we get:
>   $$ \frac{v}{g}(k\sin\theta+v)\frac{xg}{kv\cos\theta}-vt = 0 $$
>   Assuming that $ v \neq 0 $ you get that $v$ is:
>   $$ v = \frac{xk\sin\theta}{kt\cos\theta-x} $$